# Unable to fetch the Jenkins log by using logstash plugin

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I just deployed "Logstash plugin" on Jenkins, and used Syslog Index type to fetch record.

The configuration looks like below:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHUSd.png

Note: Entered valid host name in host name text field.

The docker image is running on Linux box as like below:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                              NAMES
166a9a988d64        sebp/elk            "/usr/local/bin/star…"   5 hours ago         Up 5 hours          0.0.0.0:5044->5044/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp   elk
```

The kibana is up and running but didn't find any traces so far.

Can anyone please guide me the way to **scrape** the Jenkins console (Execution status of application (JUNIT)) and showcase it to Kibana using Logstash plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that you are listing on 5044 using TCP only, but you are sending using UDP, you need to listen using UDP or change it to send using TCP.

Comment: Can you please help me on this ? How can i change this to TCP

Comment: Change `UDP` to `TCP` in Logstsh Jenkins Plugin configuration ...

Comment: I tried but no luck...